# Allocating the proper memory for a function that recieves a structure

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, heapsort

Im trying to create a dynamic database where I can modify its size.
This is the code that I have written so far where I assign the product char pointer to `null` and price to `-1`
What I would expect for it is to have created the data base and let me keep creating new ones with new sizes which replace the old database but so far it only returns a memory direction and stops the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct _product_t {
    char *product;
    float price;
} product_t;


product_t *newDatabase(product_t *database, int *dbSize, int newSize) {
    free(database);
    product_t *newdatabase = (product_t*)malloc(sizeof(database)*newSize);
    newdatabase->product = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    newdatabase->product = NULL;
    newdatabase->price = -1;
    free(newdatabase->product);
    return newdatabase;
}
int main(void) {
    product_t *database = NULL;
    int dbSize = 0;
    char cmd;
    do{
        printf("Command?");
        scanf(" %c", &cmd);
        switch (cmd) {

        case 'q':
            printf("Bye!");
            break;
        case 'n':
            printf("Size? ");
            int newSize2 = 0;
            scanf("%d", newSize2);
            newDatabase(database, &dbSize, newSize2);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unkown command '%c'\n",cmd);
            }
    }while(cmd != 'q');
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", newSize2);` is wrong, it should be `&newSize2`. Your compiler probably told you that and you ignored it.

Comment: `sizeof(database)` should be `sizeof(*database)`

Comment: You should use `realloc()` rather than `malloc()`, so you don't lose all the old data that was in `database`.

Comment: `main()` needs to do `database = newDatabase(database, &dbSize, newSize2)`

Comment: What is the `dbSize` parameter of `newDatabase()` for? You never use it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `realloc()` to change the size of an allocation. The size of the array should use `sizeof(*database)`, since `sizeof(database)` is just the size of a pointer, not the size of the structure.

When initializing the new array elements, you need a loop. `newdatabase` points to the beginning of the array, not the new elements that were added.

```
product_t *newDatabase(product_t *database, int *dbSize, int newSize) {
    // Free the old `product` pointers if we're shrinking
    for (int i = newSize; i < *dbSize; i++) {
        free(database[i].product);
    }
    product_t *newdatabase = realloc(database, sizeof(*database)*newSize);
    if (!newdatabase && newSize != 0) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // initialize the new pointers if we're growing
    for (int i = *dbSize; i < newSize; i++) {
        newdatabase[i].product = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
        newdatabase[i].price = -1;
    }
    *dbSize = newSize;
    return newdatabase;
}
```

You also need to fix the line that asks for the size:

```
            scanf("%d", newSize2);
```

Except when reading a string, you need to pass the address of the variable to write into, so it should be:

```
            scanf("%d", &newSize2);
```

Comment: Second function parameter not right.

Comment: Might want to mention the broken `scanf("%d")` for a more complete answer.

Comment: whats wrong with the scanf function

Comment: @Michael see my comment about that on the original question, above.

Comment: Yeah I saw your comment but the point of the scanf   
 ("%d", newSize2); is that its always being changed. If I were to apply the changes it then gives me an error in the function of taking an integer from a pointer.

Comment: @Michael With `scanf("%d", newSize2)` the compiler should be (correctly) giving you a warning. It expects a pointer, and you're providing an int. Changing it to `scanf("%d", &newSize2)` is the solution, and the warning goes away.

Comment: I am running into the problem where after giving it 2 new sizes it stops.

Comment: Without seeing how you're using the pointer after calling `newDatabase()`, it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @barmar the second parameter to the function: `&dbSize` needs changed to `int *dbSize`. Would also remove the cast and the sizeof() on the malloc(). Then we can all upvote it and forget about it.

Comment: Fixed the dbSize parameter. I'm not religiously against `sizeof(char)`, I think it makes the intent clear that you're allocating space for an array of `char`.

Comment: @Barmar The only thing you've not got, that has been suggested, is freeing the `product` pointers if the database shrinks. i.e. a loop before the realloc(). Note that they might be NULL - seems like this an option that is being considered.

Comment: Oh right, forgot about those. Don't have to worry about `NULL` since `free()` handles that automatically.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Since `realloc()` can (and I assume usually does) do that itself, I don't see the need for it here. I fixed the incorrect order of freeing.

Answer (score 0):

Latest fully working version, thanks a lot for the help everyone!

```
#include <stdio.h>
            #include <string.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>


            typedef struct _product_t {
                char *product;
                float price;
            } product_t;


            product_t *newDatabase(product_t *database, int *dbSize, int newSize) {
                // Free the previous memory allocated for the database
                free(database);

                // Allocate new space for newSize products on the heap
                database = (product_t*) malloc(newSize * sizeof(product_t));

                // Initialize all products in the database with NULL and -1
                for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
                    database[i].product = NULL;
                    database[i].price = -1;
                }

                // Update the database size
                *dbSize = newSize;

                // Return the pointer to the new database
                return database;
            }
            int main(void) {
                product_t *database = NULL;
                int dbSize = 0;
                char cmd;
                do{
                    printf("Command?");
                    scanf(" %c", &cmd);
                    switch (cmd) {

                    case 'q':
                        printf("Bye!");

                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        printf("Size? ");
                        int newSize2 = 0;
                        scanf("%d", &newSize2);
                        if(newSize2 < 0) {
                            printf("Must be larger than 0");
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                        database = newDatabase(database, &dbSize, newSize2);
                        break;
                        }
                    default:
                        printf("Unkown command '%c'\n",cmd);
                        }
                }while(cmd != 'q');
                return 0;

            }
```

Working solution was found through the help of everyone thanks

Comment: Explain your answer for the benfit of others. Please don't just dump a whole page of code and expect others to dig into it.